# keycloak authentication server and resource server interaction

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-security, keycloak

I have two modules in my application. The first module contains Keycloak with Swagger implementation, and the second module has the REST APIs I want to protect with Single Sign-On (SSO). How can I secure the endpoints in the second module in a way that they are authenticated by the first module before accessing the APIs?

I've attempted to use Keycloak adapters and authentication providers, but they seem to cause issues during application startup rather than providing a solution.

Comment: Please provide additional details on what you've tried and errors received, including config and logs.

Comment: what is version of `spring-boot` in second module ?